# How to ask politely to my lecturer requesting for a make up class?

Tags: politeness

I am an undergraduate student in Indonesia. I would like to ask for a make up class to my lecturer because the day that the class is supposed to be is a day between two holidays (it's called as "Harpitnas" in Indonesia, one working day sandwiched between two holidays). Is the below word already okay?

> Good day, Mr. X. Most of my friends in SLA 205 class can't seem to
>   make our next Monday class. Next Monday will be a so-called
>   "Harpitnas" day. I am afraid if most of them will be absent because of
>   the day. I am wondering if you'd be glad to make the class off for
>   another time, Sir. Thank you and sorry for any inconvenience, Sir.

I appreciate every answer that is inside the topic. Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi, Alvian. While James has proposed an answer for you, I personally think yours is fine as is. At most, I would add a footnote about what Harptinas is just as you had done for us, especially if you feel like your lecturer will not understand the term.

Comment: One too many "Sirs" at the end, in my opinion, but that could be cultural. Anyway, I'm surprised this hasn't garnered any close votes for proofreading.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang Thank you. My lecturer surely knows it because he is Indonesian. Most Indonesian people will know it.

Comment: @J.R.That's right. It is our culture. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more formal if you write a letter to him as a group, since you're not the only one going.

Dear Sir,

Permission To Be Absent Next Monday

Good day sir. Next Monday is Herpitnas Day, a local  holiday. Many of us in SLA 205 will want to actively participate in the holiday.

Since we are having your class on that day, we would be immensely grateful if you can skip the class for our sake. Or, if you can do a make-up class for us later.

We are deeply sorry for any inconvenience whatsoever, sir. Thank you as you consider our plea.

Yours faithfully,

For: SLA 205 Class

Signature

Comment: You're welcome my friend. Glad you found it helpful. @Alvian

Comment: @AlvianCasablancas, you've probably already sent the email, but for the future, I would have just written, "Next Monday is a harpitnas." Harpitnas is not an actual holiday, right? It had sounded to me like it's just the term for a workday sandwiched between two holidays.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is whether your note is polite.  It is polite.  It is written in a very sincere way and in your own words.  I have been both a professor and a student and I think you've done a good job conveying your concern and suggesting a possible solution without being unreasonable, pushy or needy.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It makes me confident with my own words.